Replacing mud bed over concrete for tile installation
I'm renovating a small (5' x 5') half bath/powder room in an old (1930s) house. I've removed the existing floor tile and what's under it seems to be about 2" thick mud bed on top of a concrete subfloor. The mud bed looks to be in pretty bad shape, and since the room is so small I'm considering taking it out entirely.
My question then: when I get the old mud bed out, what's the best way to prepare the concrete subfloor for tiling that also accounts for the 2 inches lost from removing the mud bed? Should I just lay down a new mud bed or are there more modern options that'd be better suited for installing tile floor at the same height as the old tile floor?
Thanks!
